# CSS Custom cursor not working, does browsers not support it anymore?

Tags: html, css, cursor

```
 body {cursor: url(cursor/NB_Arrow.cur);}
```

in stylesheet

This line of code is what I saw how to do it on all the other stackoverflow answers but it doesn't seem to be working. my cursor stays the same as normal default arrow cursor.

**Does browsers not support it anymore** these days or have I done a typo in my code

Tried it on IE, Latest Chrome and Latest Firefox all not working

Comment: to be sure the cursor file is available, you're using relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url):

> **Syntax**
>
> This means that zero or more URLs may be specified (comma-separated),
>   which **must** be followed by one of the keywords defined in the CSS
>   specification, such as auto or pointer.

So try using:

```
body {
    cursor: url(cursor/NB_Arrow.cur), auto;
}
```

Comment: Tried that on Mozilla Firefox, cursor still default normal one for some reason

Comment: actually it the , auto at the end was what I needed, the browser didn't fully refresh the webpage to load in that extra word

Comment: @Friedpanseller it worked and you don't need any keyword after, right?

Comment: @Adrift just tried it, it's really required, I have not used custom cursor but the book I'm reading just says it's some kind of fallback. I would like to say that the way CSS3 proposed that rule is **very annoying** and unnatural at all. If the keyword is missing, normally it should be understood as `default`, the `url` if exists **should still work**. It's a very weird behavior.

Comment: @KingKing: I completely agree.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url

Seems to still be supported...

http://jsfiddle.net/7xFDM/3/

```
    .test {
   /* cursor: pointer;*/
    cursor: url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-view/63374.gif), auto;
    }
```